# Passing template URL to directive from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to send template url from controller to the directive. Hardcoding the template url works fine. Here is what works:

```
<div my-directive template-url = "my-template.html" ></div>
```

And in directive

```
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        templateUrl: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
            return tAttrs.templateUrl;
        },
        controller: 'myController as myCtrl',
        scope: {
            myDirective: '='
        }
    };
```

But I want to use my controller variable when specifying the template-url in the directive. So I tried:

```
<div nav-switcher template-url="baseCtrl.directiveUrl" ></div>
```

For which Im getting error message:

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: "baseCtrl.directiveUrl"
```

How to pass controller variable to the directive ?

Comment: i don't know if i understand it. just create a $scope.directiveUrl on your controller and call it on the HTML with {{directiveURL}}

Comment: Then it gives an error `Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: {{baseCtrl.directiveUrl}}`

Comment: Could you please show us the controller where `directiveUrl` is declared.

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps if you change you HTML to

```
<div nav-switcher template-url="{{directiveUrl}}" ></div>
```

The braces will evaluate the expression to text.